# Nginx File name Case Insensitive

Tags: nginx

I want case insensitive for my php file. 
I tried :

```
location ~* / {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

    }
```

I get 500 Internal Server. Where is error? Thanks in  advance

Comment: There is error.log. Here you have infinite rewrite loop. Why did you write `location ~* /`?

Comment: For be case insensitive.This config not get internal server error.It's cause download my index.php file

Comment: No I mean, why is it regexp at all?

Comment: So, what should I do

Comment: It depends on what do you want to get.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't tell my problem exactly. For example , i have a x.php. I want in that include "X.php"; This work on apache but don't work on nginx.

Comment: Can't see how including X.php and rewriting everything to /index.php are connected